# Using profiles in multimodule project

Tags: maven-3, maven-profiles

I have a multimodule maven project. Project layout is described below:

```
PARENT
  |-CHILD1
  |-CHILD2
```

Parent project has pom packaging type and declares `CHILD1` and `CHILD2` projects as modules. Also `PARENT` project declares profile `dev` which declares some property.
CHILD1 project has jar packaging type and "overrides" PARENT `dev` profile by adding some dependency(dependency on `commons-collections` for example).
CHILD2 project has war packaging type and has dependency on CHILD1 project. Also CHILD2 "overrides" parent `dev` profile by adding another dependency(dependency on `commons-io` for example, I mean dependency that is not related with that one in project CHILD1).
Then when I run `mvn clean install -Pdev` maven doesn't put `commons-collections.jar`(dependency that is declared in CHILD1 project) to `WEB-INF/lib` of CHILD2 project, but commons-io.jar is there.

So, the question is: Why does not maven put dependencies from profiles that are declared in dependent projects of target project if target project declares another set of dependencies in that profile?

Actually I have much more projects and much more dependencies that varies in different profiles. And I want to declare project specific dependencies in that project pom.xml(supposing that declaring profile in project will "override" parent profile declaration)

Comment: Adding dependencies with a profile is a **major anti-pattern** and should not have been allowed in the original POM format specification.

Comment: How to act in the case when I need different dependencies in different profiles? I need to exclude some dependencies in some profiles

Comment: Use different modules and webapp overlays to add the modules in to the reactor via profiles. IOW you will have three or four webapp modules, all but one will be 'empty' with just dependencies on the base webapp and the additional dependencies you need

Comment: You need to keep in mind that when the artifacts get deployed to the repository, you loose the active profile information, so consumers pulling the dependency from the repository will not pull the dependencies that are pulled in via a profile (unless by accident they happen to have a profile with the exact same name active) so you really need separate artifacts to have separate dependencies

Comment: So, I have to create a project per profile, I mean if a module have dependencies that varies in profiles I have to create a submodule of that module and add specific dependencies to that module(module without sources and resources, only with declaration of dependencies) and in the module declare only common dependencies?

Comment: s/submodule/sibling module/g but yeah that's sort of the idea. Better yet is to avoid including any environment specific bits in your artifacts. So for example I have (closed source) a respin of jetty for prod & test & dev environments that has the configuration for each environment baked in. You just drop the artifact into the distribution and it picks up all the dependencies for that distribution. You really want each artifact's dependencies to be constant. That is the solution you are aiming for, how you achieve that depends on your needs

Comment: For example, if you are developing a web-app, I would add the impl jars to the jetty plugin's dependencies via a profile.... hmmm I'll knock up an answer for this

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to be able to test locally when developing, test your changes against a staging environment and finally deploy to production.

The critical thing that you need to keep in mind is that when an artifact gets deployed to the local/remote repository, the active profiles is not part of what gets deployed, so when you add dependencies via profiles things become very dangerous as you have no way of knowing if the webapp was built with the DEV profile active or the PROD profile active, and then when that built artifact gets deployed into production you could be royally screwed over.

So the short of this is that you ensure that your artifacts are independent of deployment environment.

This means that, for example, you will pick up configuration from:

- files on the classpath
- system properties
- jndi entries

So for example, if deploying to Tomcat, you might put a configuration.properties into `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`

Your webapp on startup will use `getClass().getResource('/configuration.properties')` to resolve the properties file and fail to start-up if the file is missing (fail-fast)

you can let your unit/integration tests use a different config by putting a test version of configuration.properties in `src/test/resources`.

You use the same principle for the `<scope>provided</scope>` style dependencies of your application. In otherwords a dependency that the container is contracted with providing should be provided by the container. So you might build the production version of tomcat/jetty for yourself using Maven also and add in the required dependencies into that assembly. This would be things like the production version uses a MySQL database, so you need to add the mysql-jdbc driver into to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. It is relatively easy to do this with the assembly plugin as you are really just repacking a zip with some bits included and others excluded.

When testing locally you will want to make use of the helper plugins' `run` goals such as `jetty:run` and `tomcat:run`. The solution here is that there is nothing wrong with giving these plugins dependencies via profiles *because you are not affecting the dependencies of the artifact* you are only affecting the plugin's classpath.

e.g.

```
<project>
  <!-- ... some stuff .. -->
  <profiles>
     <profile>
       <id>DEV</id>
       <build>
         <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                 <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                 <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                 <version>1.4</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                 <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                 <version>5.1.18</version>
               </dependency>
             </dependencies>
           </plugin>
         </plugins>
       </build>
     </profile>
   </profiles>
 </project>
```

You can also configure system properties or classpath additions to pull in the required configuration file.

The net result of all this is that the artifact remains environment independent and you can test easily against the various environments

Hope this answers your question (even if sideways)

Comment: It doesn't depend on environment. I simply want to exclude some dependencies or provide dependecies without some transitives or provide dependencies with different scope based on (for example) input arguments of maven build command. To provide artifact with information about profile I can use classifier and activate it(classifier) in different profiles. So the question is still open

Comment: Classifiers have the same dependencies as the main artifact, so classifiers is a false solution. Maven is opinionated, you are trying to do something that it firmly believes to be a "bad thing" so the net result is you will fight it all the way.... good luck.... and good luck 6 months later trying to figure out exactly what you did!