# Using different JBoss BOM in profiles

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, maven-bom

I have a general question about the usage of the BOM from JBoss and WildFly.
Is the a way to build a project for both JBoss 7 and WildFly 10 using a different profile?

I tried to copy the BOM definition from WildFly into a profile like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>WildFly10</id>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>         
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- JSON -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>${version.json}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</profile>
```

Of course accourdingly with a JBoss7 profile.

But this way it won't add important libraries to the lib folder, i.e. this definition is in an ear pom and a subproject (war) adds the json dependency. Without a profile maven adds the json jar inside the lib folder, but not if I put it inside a profile.

After I read that changing dependencies in a profile is an anti-pattern [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940670/using-profiles-in-multimodule-project)] I would like to know how I can build my project for both JBoss7 and WildFly 10.

**Update**

Ok sorry for this quick shot of a question. Here are more details.

project structure:

```
|-parent (pom)
  |- myapp (war)
  |- core (jar)
  |- deployment (ear)
```

So `deployment` is the project building the whole ear containing `myapp` as a web apllication and `core` as a library. `myapp` has a dependency to `core` and `core` to `json`.

In order to have all needed depenedencies with the correct version I included `wildfly-javaee7-with-tools` in the dependencyManagment. Also is the version of `json` defined in there. The `core` project has the `json` library as a normal dependency.

At this point this should be quite standard. But the thing is I want to be able to build for JBoss 7 and WildFly 10, for what I have to change

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

to

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Of course `${version.jboss.bom}` will be changed from `10.1.0.Final` for WildFly to `1.0.7.Final` for JBoss.

In order to do so I tried to move `wildfly-javaee7-with-tools` into a profile. My first guess was to only move this dependency to a profile. But then the `json` jar doesn't get included. After that I also tried to move `json`like above.

Comment: Sorry, off-topic, can you link perhaps this stuff _changing dependencie in a profile is an anti-pattern_? And possibly edit to the question to contain the relevant parts from non-profile pom or is it only that one pom/import dependency?

Comment: "Without a profile maven adds the json jar inside the lib folder" -- Can you show a pom for this?

Comment: Actually there is nothing special at this pom. It just has some dependecies. One of them is a different subproject (jar) with the JSON dependency. When I have no profiles at all, the JSON jar is added, but if I just wrap it in a profile it won't be included.

Comment: What are you gaining by using the `wildfly-javaee7-with-tools` bom instead of `jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools`? If you just use the latter your application should deploy and run on both platforms.

Comment: It has some different version numbers for some libraries like jsf and hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the original not-profiled nor profiled pom in whole cannot say anything accurate but educated guess.

You have `json` in profiles dependency management.

Is it also in `pom`s main dependencies without version? If not it will not be copied to lib nor packed. It is only managed by profiles `<dependencyManagement>`.

Does `json` need managing per profile? It seems to have `${version.json}` which then anyway would be same for each profile if copied as it is in the example.

For me it seems that fix might be that you remove the `json` from profiles dependencyManagement and add it to main dependencies as normal dependency - this just to make profiling more simple - it can be managed but if not needed set the version of `json` directly  to dependency.